# Verite's timeline js ERA and BC error

Tags: javascript, timeline

I'm trying to create a timeline using timeline. (http://timeline.verite.co/)
The problem is I can't go back more than 9000 BC and if I add ERA to JSON object, the timeline get's all messed up (starting further and the line off place and era overlapped).

Can you please tell me how to do this? (use eras and 10000+ BC)

Also found this: [Can you create dates that are lower than 271800 BC? Like dinosaur time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860297/can-you-create-dates-that-are-lower-than-271800-bc-like-dinosaur-time)
How can I get past this?

this is my JSON

```
    {
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"XXX",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"TEXTTTT",
        "startDate":"-11000",

        "date": [
            {
                "startDate":"-7000",
                "endDate":"",
                "headline":"title 1",
                "text":"text 1"
            },
            {
                "startDate":"-4000",
                "endDate":"",
                "headline":"title 2",
                "text":"text 2"
            },
            {
                "startDate":"-2500",
                "endDate":"",
                "headline":"title 3",
                "text":"text 3"
            }           
        ],

        "era": [
            {
                "startDate":"10000",
                "endDate":"8000",
                "headline":"Era 1",
                "text":"<p>Body text goes here, some HTML is OKs</p>",
                "tag":"This is Optionals"
            },
            {
                "startDate":"-4000",
                "endDate":"-3000",
                "headline":"Era 2",
                "text":"<p>Body text goes here, some HTML is OK</p>",
                "tag":"This is Optional"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Valid javascript dates range from 271,821bc to  275,760ad.
>
> Great spans of time are understood as comparative numbers- so many
>   days or hours, using days or hours as lengths or distance from the
>   present. Dates are significant for recent or near future events,
>   beyond that you don't need and can't trust them.

```
var d= 8.64e15;
var bcMin=new Date(-d),
bcMax=new Date(d);

['minimum Date Object: '+bcMin.toUTCString(),
'minimum date minus 1 day:'+
bcMin.setDate(bcMax.getDate()+1),
'maximum Date Object: '+bcMax.toUTCString(),
'maximum date plus 1 day:'+
bcMax.setDate(bcMax.getDate()+1)].join('\n').replace(/\-(\d+)/g,'$1bce');



> returned value: (String)
>     minimum Date Object: Tue, 20 Apr 271821bce 00:00:00 GMT
>     minimum date minus 1 day:NaN
>     maximum Date Object: Sat, 13 Sep 275760 00:00:00 GMT
>     maximum date plus 1 day:NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I still can't have dates that go beyond [-9999, 99999]... And eras are still messing up my timeline. How must I update my JSON?