# javascript clock on website, two timezones

Tags: javascript

I would like to have two clocks on my website: one with local time, other with GMT+1. Everything works when i use the codes separetly, but when together, only second one works. What have I done wrong?

```js
<div id="clockbox2" style="height: 100%px; width: 100%; color:#fff">
<script type="text/javascript">
tday=new Array("воскресение","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","суббота");
tmonth=new Array("января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря");

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML="<br>"+nhour+":"+nmin+"<br>"+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+" "+tmonth[nmonth]+", "+nyear+" г.";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
</script>
</div>
```

```js
<div id="clockbox2" style="height: 100%px; width: 100%; color:#fff">
<script type="text/javascript">
tday=new Array("воскресение","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","суббота");
tmonth=new Array("января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря");

function GetClock2(){
var tzOffset = -5;//set this to the number of hours offset from UTC
var d=new Date();
var dx=d.toGMTString();
dx=dx.substr(0,dx.length -3);
d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
d.setHours(d.getHours()+tzOffset);

var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin
document.getElementById('clockbox2').innerHTML="<br>"+nhour+":"+nmin+"<br>"+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+" "+tmonth[nmonth]+", "+nyear+" г.";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock2();
setInterval(GetClock2,1000);
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see either of them working in the code snippet ?

Comment: @smoggers i posted them in javascript window, but should had in html :/

Comment: Just as a hint: Have you had a look to [`momentum.js`](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Please use : [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- Both `_div_` elements have the same *id*: `id = clockbox2` (that is the main problem)
- The `height` indicates `100%px`, you need to choose one of the units
- No need to use any workaround to [calculate the years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178930/5247200), use `getFullYear` instead of `getYear`
- It is not a *programming* issue, but we will see nothing in a SO snippet if you set the font color to white: `color=#fff` :)

Regarding the main question, use this for the second time zone:

```
d2.setHours(d2.getHours() - 5);
```

As long that is the number of hours offset from UTC.

I leave you here a snippet with a correct formatting:

```js
tday=new Array("воскресение","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","суббота");
tmonth=new Array("января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря");

function GetClock(){

var d1= new Date();
var d2= new Date();
d2.setHours(d2.getHours() - 5);

var nday1=d1.getDay();
var nmonth1=d1.getMonth();
var ndate1=d1.getDate();
var nyear1=d1.getFullYear();
var nhour1=d1.getHours();

var nday2=d2.getDay();
var nmonth2=d2.getMonth();
var ndate2=d2.getDate();
var nyear2=d2.getFullYear();
var nhour2=d2.getHours();


var nmin=d1.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9)
  nmin="0"+nmin;
  

document.getElementById('clockbox1').innerHTML = "<br>"+nhour1+":"+nmin+"<br>"+tday[nday1]+", "+ndate1+" "+tmonth[nmonth1]+", "+nyear1+" г.";

document.getElementById('clockbox2').innerHTML = "<br>"+nhour2+":"+nmin+"<br>"+tday[nday2]+", "+ndate2+" "+tmonth[nmonth2]+", "+nyear2+" г.";

}

window.onload=function(){

setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="clockbox1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; color:#000"></div>
<div id="clockbox2" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; color:#000"></div>
```

Hope it helps!